# Customize function by using JavaDSL

Tags: citrus-framework

I would like to know how can I create a customize function in java code instead of XML? I know how to add my function in the XML function library. But is there another way to add to the library in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add function libraries as Spring Beans to the application context. This is all you have to do in order to use your custom functions in Citrus:

```
@Bean
public FunctionLibrary customFunctionLib() {
    FunctionLibrary functionLibrary = new FunctionLibrary();

    functionLibrary.setPrefix("foolib:");
    functionLibrary.setName("fooFunctionLibrary");

    functionLibrary.getMembers().put("fooFunction", new FooFunction());
    return functionLibrary;
}
```

After that you should be able to call the function with `foolib:fooFunction()`.